# Get user count based on multiple meta key values?

Tags: user-meta, array, count

I am trying to count all of the users meeting multiple criteria. I have tried so many different things and cannot get it to work. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
add_shortcode('pbe_storecount', 'pbe_shopcounts');
function pbe_shopcounts($atts) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'state'   => '',
    'metavalue' => do_shortcode('[display_name]'),
    'userrole'  => '',
), $atts );
$getQuarter = do_shortcode('[usermeta key="current_quarter" user="717"]');
if ($getQuarter == '1'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1';
} elseif ($getQuarter == '2'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1_89';
    } elseif ($getQuarter == '3'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1_90';
} elseif ($getQuarter == '4'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1_91';
    } else {
        $currentQuarter = '';
}
$user_ids = get_users( $args );
$args = array (
  'role__in'    => wp_parse_list( $atts['userrole'] ),
  'fields'      => 'ID',  // retrieve just the IDs
  'count_total' => false, // no need for FOUND_ROWS()
  'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'meta_key'     => 'Group',
        'meta_value'   => $atts['metavalue'],
        'meta_compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'meta_key'       => $currentQuarter,
        'meta_value'     => 'High',
        'meta_compare' => '=',
    ),
    )
    );
return 'There are <strong>' . count( $user_ids ) . ' High Performers</strong> for ' . $atts['metavalue'] . ' in ' . $atts['state'] . '!';}
```

Comment: You may try to define $args before using it in get_users( $args ).

Comment: Thank you, @Knut. That's certainly a start; however, I made the correction and it still just counts all of the users in the roles specified in the shortcode parameter. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, I changed "meta_key" and "meta_value" to just "key" and "value", then removed the "compare", and it worked.